# Where can I see a full list of ExampleData?

Tags: curated-data

Using ExampleData, we can extract data for [Machine Learning](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/highly-automated-machine-learning/predict-the-survival-of-titanic-passengers.html), [Sound](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/highly-automated-machine-learning/recognize-wind-instruments-from-their-sound.html) and others. From the reference of the Wolfram Language, I can see a full list of types of data, like machine learning, dataset, audio, etc. But where can I see what data can I extract for every type?

Comment: See answer for [ExampleData menu view](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54585/9362)

Comment: `ExampleData /@ ExampleData[]`. If you have time to kill: `Scan[Echo, Flatten[ExampleData /@ ExampleData[], 1]]`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the useful link

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get the categories of example data:

```
ExampleData[]
(* {"AerialImage", "Audio", "ColorTexture", "Dataset", \
"Geometry3D", "LinearProgramming", "MachineLearning", "Matrix", \
"NetworkGraph", "Sound", "Statistics", "TestAnimation", "TestImage", \
"TestImage3D", "TestImageSet", "Text", "Texture"} *)
```

Get the available data in one category:

```
ExampleData["MachineLearning"]
(* {{"MachineLearning", "BostonHomes"}, {"MachineLearning", 
  "FisherIris"}, {"MachineLearning", "MNIST"}, {"MachineLearning", 
  "MovieReview"}, {"MachineLearning", "Mushroom"}, {"MachineLearning",
   "Satellite"}, {"MachineLearning", "Titanic"}, {"MachineLearning", 
  "UCILetter"}, {"MachineLearning", "WineQuality"}} *)
```

Get available properties of one dataset:

```
ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "BostonHomes"}, "Properties"]
(* {"Data", "Description", "Data", "Dimensions", \
"LearningTask", "LongDescription", "MissingData", "Name", "Source", \
"TestData", "TrainingData", "VariableDescriptions", "VariableTypes"} *)
```